# Selecionar dados de três tabelas SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, query, firebird, join

estou tentando juntar dados de três tabelas usando esse sql:

```
SELECT cod_nota, cupom, valor_contrato, valor_cadastro, data_emissao
FROM cupons_nota, vendas, notas_fiscais
WHERE cupons_nota.cupom = vendas.numero_nf AND notas_fiscais.cod_cliente='00000212' AND data_emissao BETWEEN '01.03.2018' AND '30.04.2018'
ORDER BY cod_nota ASC;
```

O problema é que ele ta retornando os dados triplicados, e eu queria apenas uma única vez o dado.

Exemplo do resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Qual o resultado esperado?

Comment: ele retorna "triplicado" porque você deve ter 3 notas pra esse cliente. Repito a pergunta de @RobertodeCampos, "qual o resultado esperado"?

Comment: O resultado esperado era uma única linha, e não as três.

Comment: se tiver que agregar alguma coluna (somar, média, max, min) use o `group by`. Se os dados estão corretos e só estão duplicando por causa do join, use o `Distinct`

Comment: como ficaria usando o Distinct?

Comment: Select distinct .........(tudo igual já está).....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para agrupar os resultados utilizamos o `GROUP BY` com o(s) campo(s) que serão agrupados, no seu caso, seria o campo `cod_nota`:

```
SELECT cod_nota, cupom, valor_contrato, valor_cadastro, data_emissao
FROM cupons_nota, vendas, notas_fiscais
WHERE cupons_nota.cupom = vendas.numero_nf AND notas_fiscais.cod_cliente='00000212' AND data_emissao BETWEEN '01.03.2018' AND '30.04.2018'
GROUP BY cod_nota
ORDER BY cod_nota ASC;
```

Caso você precise somar os resultados de uma coluna utilize a função `SUM`:

```
SELECT cod_nota, cupom, SUM(valor_contrato) valor_contrato, SUM(valor_cadastro) valor_cadastro, data_emissao
FROM cupons_nota, vendas, notas_fiscais
WHERE cupons_nota.cupom = vendas.numero_nf AND notas_fiscais.cod_cliente='00000212' AND data_emissao BETWEEN '01.03.2018' AND '30.04.2018'
GROUP BY cod_nota
ORDER BY cod_nota ASC;
```

Comment: Quando tentei agora, ele voltou o seguinte erro: Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Comment: Qual erro foi retornado?

Comment: porque não tem nenuma agregação... use o `Distinct`

Comment: Deu certo, obrigado galera!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer a consulta assim.

```
SELECT cod_nota, cupom, valor_contrato, valor_cadastro, data_emissao
FROM cupons_nota join vendas on id_tabela1=id_tabela2 join notas_fiscais on id_tabela2 = id id_tabela3 WHERE cupons_nota.cupom = vendas.numero_nf AND notas_fiscais.cod_cliente='00000212' AND data_emissao BETWEEN '01.03.2018' AND '30.04.2018'
ORDER BY cod_nota ASC;
```